# Installation failed: Could not create directory. wordpress 4.7.1 plugin installation

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, fedora-21

I am getting Installation failed: Could not create the directory. error while installation of WordPress plugin, I have changed the permission of WordPress directory to 775 and also set

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/*
```

i tried to accesss the plugings direcotry by

```
sudo -u apache touch /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/test.txt
```

and i am able to create test.txt file. then also i am not able to istall plugins. i am using fedora 21 system

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to the absence of permission given to the wordpress files. All the folder permissions should be 755.

`chmod -R 755 /for all folders`

And all the file permissions should be 644.

`chmod -R 644 /all the files`

You can also check the wordpress GUI and check the site health(Tools > site health)if your health status is not good, scroll down and see the errors over there,needed permission for each file will be mentioned over there and give the permissions accordingly.

**Only for try**

`chmod -R 777 /parent folder where all the files are included`
if this works you can confirm that your issue is with the permission.If that didnt work check out the memory and the wp-config.php file

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WP-CLI you could try the command below:
`sudo wp plugin install [plugin name] --allow-root`

This helped me solved the same problem as yours before.

Answer (score -3):

Execute bellow commands

sudo chown -R www-data:www-data  /wp-content/plugins/ 
chmod 777 /wp-content/upgrade/

open your wp-config.php file and place bellow line. 
define('FS_METHOD','direct');

Comment: upgrade directory is not there inside the wp-content

Comment: and i have added define('FS_METHOD','direct');

Comment: you should **never** chmod 777. it's a clear sign you don't know what you are doing and opens up a lot of security risks. also: OP mentioned fedora. on fedora, apache doesn't run as "www-data" but as "apache" by default.